# (Android) Apply multiple layers of text-shadow to text, like in CSS

Tags: java, android, xml, css, shadow

i was wondering if it was possible to apply `multiple layers` of shadow to a single text element, **or button** in Android with XML, or programatically. In CSS, i can do this (Separate shadow effects by a comma):

```
#myText{
text-shadow:0 0 5px #228DFF, 0 0 10px #228DFF, 0 0 15px #228DFF, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 35px #fff, 0 0 40px #228DFF, 0 0 50px #228DFF, 0 0 75px #228DFF;
}
```

Is it possible to do that in Android? Or is there `a hack` of some sort to achieve this effect?